# Can I disable the native rectangle selection of recent Viewer versions?

Tags: autodesk-viewer

Recent versions of the Autodesk Forge Viewer implemented a rectangle selection tool, by using the ctrl key. We've already implemented a multi-selection tool (using the blog post https://forge.autodesk.com/blog/custom-window-selection-forge-viewer-simpler-extension), and it uses the ctrl key to add to the current selection. The issue is that, when the ctrl key is pressed, the native tool activates, and since the native behavior is to deselect all before selecting, we can't make our tool to work as intended.

Is it possible to disable the ctrl key activation of the native tool? Searching the Viewer source for key presses is very hard, and I couldn't find anything pointing to this tool.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may pass an option `disabledExtensions` like the below to prevent Forge Viewer from loading the `Autodesk.BoxSelection` extension automatically.

```js
const config3d = {
  disabledExtensions: { boxSelection: true }
};

const viewer = new Autodesk.Viewing.Private.GuiViewer3D( viewerDiv, config3d );
```